# Tests for subjective vs objective obligation

Tags: modal-verbs

Given a modal of obligation, what would be a good way to explore whether it expresses subjective/self-imposed or objective/externally imposed obligation (or whether there is no distinction along those lines)?

Here's an example of the kind of sentence I'm thinking of:

not must come early amongst possibilities ~ you didn't have to come early.

Either the meaning is "It would have been fine if you hadn't felt you had to come early" (subjective obligation) or it's "It would have been been fine if you hadn't come early" ("amongst possibilities" redundant). How do I tell which is the correct reading?

To test this, I guess I need to come up with a scenario where there is an obligation that's clearly subjective in nature and one where the obligation is clearly objective. This is harder than it sounds, though, not least because obligations that seem subjective (*I x get my hair cut*, *I x get a better job*) might actually be socially imposed, be family obligations, etc. Maybe *I x pay that bill today - it's due next week* would be better, but it seems a bit contrived.

Are there better test sentences, or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Are you talking about a computational procedure, or syntactic tests for deontic versus epistemic modality?